# expandable list with json

Tags: android, json, expandablelistview

I would like to know your opinion. I am getting some data from json and would like to represent it in expandable list view.

```
 JSONObject obj = null;
    listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
    listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

    try {
        for(int i =0;i<json.length();i++){
            obj = json.getJSONObject(0);

            String id= obj.get("id").toString();
            String parentId= obj.get("parentId").toString();
            String label= obj.get("label").toString();
            String labelId= obj.get("labelId").toString();
```

What is the best way to create expandable list view?

Comment: Better you ask google it will help better :)

Comment: i suggests to use this very good maked guide:

http://androidexample.com/Custom_Expandable_ListView_Tutorial_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=107&aaid=129

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one helped! Also searching a little bit more on forum helps as well. Thank you all for help :)[Link](http://androidexample.com/Custom_Expandable_ListView_Tutorial_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=107&aaid=129)